# How to transmit Huffman code on a set of symbols {0,1,2,..,N-1} with 2N-1 + N*ceil(lg(n)) bits?

Tags: algorithm

This is a question from Sedgewick's book's website. He gives a hint of "use 2N-1 bits to specify the structure of the corresponding trie."

I might not understand the question, especially what he means by {0,1,2,..,N-1}. But I would use N bits to specify how many bits are needed to encode 0th, 1st etc codes in the following way:
if we have 1 in ith position, then the ith code uses i bits, if it has 0, then look at the next position with 1 in it, and that (i+x)th position will specify the number of bits (or look in the previous position if there are no ones in the next positions(for example balanced binary tree gives that)).

But that only works if the encoding trie is close to perfect, because if we have a fibonacci distribution of frequences, our encoding trie will look like this:

```
  o
 / \
o   o
   / \
  o   o
     / \
    o   o
 .....
```

Which means that in total we will have (n^2+n)/2-1 bits, after the length description bit-string (arithmetic progression for 1+2+...+N and -1 because 2 nodes have the same depth). How can I achieve the specified space complexity?

Here's a link: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/55compression/ refer to exercise 20.

Comment: Does this belong on the [computer science Stack exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com) maybe?

Comment: @WaiHaLee, I've asked plenty of such questions on here with tag "algorithm" and people answered just fine. It's more of a puzzle than something theoretical.

Comment: Aha - fair enough. An interesting puzzle, at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have these frequencies:

```
A 11
B 7
C 5
D 4
E 3
F 1
```

They generate this coding:

```
R: 0: 0:       B
      1:       C
   1: 0:       A
      1: 0:    D
         1: 0: E
            1: F
```

You can describe the structure of this trie with the array `BCADEF`, and a sequence of bits that identify a node as terminal (0) and non-terminal (1), in the depth-first order:

```
11001010100
```

(The first `110` represents the `R: 0: 0:` path - root is nonterminal, `0` is also non-terminal, and the next `0` is a terminal with the label `B`; the next `0` represents the `1:` branch, which is another terminal, labeled `C`; the next `10` are the `1: 0:` branch, terminating in `A`; etc.) This is not ambiguous, because Huffman coding is a strict binary-branch tree - a node either has two children, or none.

You will notice that `11001010100` has 11 bits, which is 2 * 6 - 1, as the formula predicts. (There are N-1 internal nodes and N leaves in a strict binary tree).

To reconstruct:

```js
function restoreTree(alphabet, structure) {
  if (structure.shift() == "0") {
    return alphabet.shift();
  } else {
    var left = restoreTree(alphabet, structure);
    var right = restoreTree(alphabet, structure);
    return [left, right];
  }
}

var alphabet = "BCADEF".split('');
var structure = "11001010100".split('');
var tree = restoreTree(alphabet, structure);
document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(tree);
```

**EDIT**: The `N * ceil(lg(N))` part describes the space requirements for the alphabet order (assuming the alphabet itself is known). For example, say you know the alphabet is `"ABCDEF"` - with positions from 0 to 5 (A = 0, F = 5). Each position can thus be represented by three bits (`ceil(lg(6)) == 3`, three bits being sufficient for `0..7`). Thus, to represent the `"BCADEF"` order, you'd translate 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5 into three bits each: `001010000011100101`. This has 18 bits, or `6 * ceil(lg(6))`. Reconstructing `"BCADEF"` from `"ABCDEF"` and `001010000011100101` should be straightforward.

Comment: Are B,C and A on the same level in your trie? I drew a trie from your frequences and they shouldn't be.

Comment: You are correct, it appears that in my mathematics 12 > 13 :). I'll change A to 11 instead of 13, that should generate the tree in the example. However, none of the rest changes - how to represent the trie (whatever it is) and how to reconstruct it.

Comment: thanks, but where does N*ceil(lgN) come from in this algorithm?

Comment: Oh. I thought the question was about the structure part (2N-1 bits). I'll add about the alphabet part.

Comment: Oh,that's true, thank you very much, somehow I totally spaced the fact that we need lgN bits for an alphabet of N elements.

Comment: I wrote binary tree by accident in the edit, I meant Huffman trie, sorry. Binary tree itself can be a linked list with 1 leaf and plenty of internal nodes.

Comment: I prefer to say "strict binary tree" - there are other strict binary trees other than Huffman tries.